# How to break down toolbar buttons on samll screens on Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a toolbar with 6 button (no image just text), when I run the app on small screen phones, you can't see them all, just the ones which can fit in the screen,
I tried these with no chance

- adding another div and dividing them into divs
- using `<br/>`

Comment: Do you need six buttons in the toolbar? The toolbar is fixed height and the font size is fixed so there's a limit to how many buttons you can fit. What about having one button with a dropdown menu that has six options? You can do that by creating a popover.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius Do you mean putting my buttons on a popover?